How can I identify the distribution of a series of Mahalanobis distances?
If my dataset follows a multivariate t-distribution, what is the cdf of the Mahalanobis distance of a datapoint outside the sample? In other words, if I want to calculate the probability that a datapoint belongs to the dataset's distribution by using its Mahalanobis distance from the distribution's mean, what cdf should I use?
In other words, I'd like to know the distribution of $d_M(\vec X, \vec \mu)$ for some $\vec X$ that has a multivariate $t$ distribution with mean $\vec\mu$, where $d_M$ is Mahalanobis distance.

Welcome to Cross Validated! As Mahalanobis distance uses variances that need not be defined for your t-distributed margins (even setting aside issues with covariances), do you know that Mahalanobis distance is even defined for your multivariate distribution?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You want to know the distribution of what? Mahalanobis is a metric, which makes it a function of two quantities, not just one. Mahalanobis distance between a point selected from the multivariate $t$ and the mean (if it exists) of that multivariate $t$, perhaps? It might be easier to state the problem in terms of a multivariate Gaussian in order to clarify what you want to know before the distribution is changed to multivariate $t$.

Thank you for your response Dave. I know when the underlying dataset is multivariate Gaussian, then the p-value of a datapoint can be computed on the squared Mahalanobis distance using the cdf of a chi-squared with dof equal to the number of predictor variables. I am looking to compute the same p-value (i.e. survival function of the Mahalanobis distance) but on t-distributed underlying dataset, with the ultimate goal of determining the probability of my datapoint (or more extreme) belonging to the distribution

Are you looking for the p-value of a hypothesis test or just a probability?

the probability that I observe a datapoint's value, or more extreme

So you want to know the distribution of $d_M(\vec X, \vec\mu)$ for some $\vec X$ that has a multivariate $t$ distribution with mean $\mu$, correct? ($d_M$ means that Mahalanobis distance.)

this is correct yes

It would be helpful to state your question these way by editing the question. Not everyone reads the comments, so questions should be self-contained.

thanks for the feedback Dave
